# Android/Facebook : Insufficient priviledges when using Api

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-sdk-4.0

On my main activity, I have the following code:

```
    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
```

I also added a button to create a post on my Facebook timeline:

```
Button b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                ShareLinkContent content = new ShareLinkContent.Builder()
                .setContentUrl(Uri.parse("https://developers.facebook.com"))
                .build();

                ShareApi.share(content, new FacebookCallback<Sharer.Result>() {

                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Result arg0) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(FacebookException arg0) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancel() {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    }
                });


            }
```

When I run my app on my smartphone, and click the button, I always get the following message (onError callback):

> Insufficient permissions for sharing content via Api.

I have configured com.facebook.app.FacebookContentProvider, com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId, com.facebook.FacebookActivity in Manifest file. And also have registered my app on facebook.

What is missing, please? Should I add a facebook Login button on my app?

Answer (score 1):

I have discovered that this error occurs when AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken() returns null. So I must authenticate to Facebook explicitly before using the ShareAPI.

I saw it in Facebook's source code available at http://android-education-project.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/facebook_4_0_0/src/com/facebook/share/ShareApi.java:

```
/**
     * Share the content.
     *
     * @param callback the callback to call once the share is complete.
     */
    public void share(FacebookCallback<Sharer.Result> callback) {
        if (!this.canShare()) {
            ShareInternalUtility.invokeCallbackWithError(
                    callback, "Insufficient permissions for sharing content via Api.");
            return;
        }
        final ShareContent shareContent = this.getShareContent();

        // Validate the share content
        try {
            ShareContentValidation.validateForApiShare(shareContent);
        } catch (FacebookException ex) {
            ShareInternalUtility.invokeCallbackWithException(callback, ex);
            return;
        }

        if (shareContent instanceof ShareLinkContent) {
            this.shareLinkContent((ShareLinkContent) shareContent, callback);
        } else if (shareContent instanceof SharePhotoContent) {
            this.sharePhotoContent((SharePhotoContent) shareContent, callback);
        } else if (shareContent instanceof ShareVideoContent) {
            this.shareVideoContent((ShareVideoContent) shareContent, callback);
        } else if (shareContent instanceof ShareOpenGraphContent) {
            this.shareOpenGraphContent((ShareOpenGraphContent) shareContent, callback);
        }

    }

/**
     * Returns true if the current access token has the publish_actions permission.
     *
     * @return true if the current access token has the publish_actions permission, false otherwise.
     */
    public boolean canShare() {
        if (this.getShareContent() == null) {
            return false;
        }
        final AccessToken accessToken = AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken();
        if (accessToken == null) {
            return false;
        }
        final Set<String> permissions = accessToken.getPermissions();
        if (permissions == null) {
            return false;
        }
        return (permissions.contains("publish_actions"));
    }
```

Comment: thank you guy, so can you share your solution for this case?

Comment: @PhanDinhThai, here is the complete solution I followed: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started

Comment: @PhanDinhThai, please take a look at the following link too: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/android